# Visualizing Euclidean Algorithm in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ with Convex Geometry

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, convex-analysis

In an attempt to answer one of the bounty questions, I have started picturing Euclidean division in quadratic fields.  In theory we would like the equation:

$$ a = b\,q + r \hspace{0.25in}\text{with}\hspace{0.25in} N(r) < \tfrac{1}{2}N(b)$$

The ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and the norm is $||a + bi|| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $, so it seems like it should be enough to show the [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset) ( or [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition))

$$ \mathbb{Z}[i] + \left\{ x^2 + y^2 < \tfrac{1}{2} \right\} = \mathbb{C}$$

and the picture confirms that Euclidean division should neatly hold in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with room to spare.

[image][image]

For $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{3})$ we can find the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]$ with norm $ ||a + \omega b|| = \sqrt{ a^2 + ab + b^2 }$.  Euclidean geometry is helping is out so far.

---

The corresponding result for $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{7})$ almost looks right but I see [tiny patches missing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236369/is-mathbbz-left-frac1i-sqrt72-right-euclidean?lq=1) and by $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{11})$ forget it.  Wikipedia says there the [norm-Euclidean quadratic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields) are $d = -1,-3,-7,-11$ and [no more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040330/what-is-a-concrete-example-to-demonstrate-that-mathcalo-mathbbq-sqrt-1).

[image]
[image]

Why is my picture of the Euclidean algorithm inaccurate?  And how to we get the missing points?

Comment: i think you want $N(r) < N(b)$ instead of $N(r) < N(b)/2$

Comment: @mercio over $\mathbb{Z}$ we say $a = bq + r$ with $0 < r < b$.  The interval $[0,b]$ is the "circle" with **diameter** $b$.  We could just as easily say $|r| < \tfrac{1}{2}b$ and get a slightly different Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: yes but we can also choose a remainder $r$ with $-b < r < b$ (a circle with radius $b$), and by induction the algorithm will still terminate.

Comment: Convex geometry or convex analysis?

Answer (score 3):

Following Mercio's comment, it's still the Euclidean algorithm if we make the ovals 2× as big.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]